# Abrindo merge request no GitLab pelo curl

Tags: libcurl, gitlab

Onde trabalho, usamos uma variação do GitFlow em que, quando uma `hotfix` entra no código do produto, há apenas o merge para o `master` que, quando aprovado, propagamos para o `develop` através do branch `master 2 develop` (ou simplesmente `m2d`).

Estou fazendo uma requisição `curl` para fazer a abertura do *merge request*. Atualmente tenho o seguinte (já com a criação do branch `m2d` o mais atualizado o possível):

```bash
git fetch
git push origin +origin/master:refs/heads/m2d

curl --request POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/merge_requests --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${mytoken}" --data "{
                \"id\": \"${project_id}\",
                \"title\": \"m2d\",
                \"source_branch\": \"m2d\",
                \"target_branch\": \"develop\"
        }"
```

Porém, obtenho a seguinte saída do `curl`:

> ```bash
> {"error":"title is missing, source_branch is missing, target_branch is missing"}
> ```

Tentei seguir as dicas [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45406313/4438007) no Stack Overflow internacional, pondo no corpo do envio as informações relevantes/o JSON, mas não consegui perceber o que estou fazendo de errado.

Eu consigo, usando o mesmo token, fazer a seguinte requisição, com sucesso:

```bash
curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${project_id} --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${mytoken}"
```

Comment: Não sei se já viu esse [post no blog deles](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/09/05/how-to-automatically-create-a-new-mr-on-gitlab-with-gitlab-ci/), tem um exemplo lá.

Comment: Não faz 5 minutos que vi, e já consegui fazer funcionar. Mas se quiser escrever a resposta e mostrar o que esqueci de mandar na requisição, ficarei grato

Comment: Caso contrário, amanhã eu respondo

Comment: Pode responder hehe não entendo muito o que diz lá rsrs, também estou sem tempo para traduzir.

Comment: @NoobSaibot, respondi, creio que tenha ficado um pouco do que a publicação do site

Comment: **Dica:** sempre que for executar algo que falhar, use o parametro `--verbose` (abreviado creio que seja `-v`), ficando assim `curl --verbose --request ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bem indicado pelo usuário [@NoobSaibot](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/60376/noobsaibot) em comentário na questão, há uma [publicação no blog do GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/09/05/how-to-automatically-create-a-new-mr-on-gitlab-with-gitlab-ci/) justamente sobre esse assunto. Específico assim. Olha o título em tradução livre:

> Como criar, automaticamente, um novo *merge request* no GitLab com GitLab-CI

Lá, ele coloca diversos exemplos do uso do comando `curl`.

Após a leitura da citada publicação, notei que há 2 caminhos para a correção do comando.

#### Solução usando JSON

Basta informar o MIME-type do envio do meu conteúdo. Bastava setar o `content-type` no *header*:

```bash
git fetch
git push origin +origin/master:refs/heads/m2d

curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/merge_requests --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${mytoken}" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data "{
            \"id\": \"${project_id}\",
            \"title\": \"m2d\",
            \"source_branch\": \"m2d\",
            \"target_branch\": \"develop\"
    }"
```

Apenas adicionei o seguitne *header* na requisição: `Content-Type: application/json`

#### Solução usando `form`

Basicamente, usando a diretiva do `curl` para envio de  formulários, a flag CLI `--form`.

```bash
curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/merge_requests \
    --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${mytoken}" \
    --form "id=${project_id}" \
    --form 'title=m2d' \
    --form 'source_branch=m2d' \
    --form 'target_branch=develop'
```