# Calcular tempo de execução de um algoritmo de ordenação em C

Tags: c, desempenho, classificação

Estou com uma dúvida sobre como obter o tempo de execução somente no algoritmo de ordenação. Rodei bastante na internet e achei muita coisa superficial, nada que me auxiliasse em que preciso.

Estou com uma questão em que eu tenho que analisar o tempo que o algoritmo leva somente para ordenar um arquivo externo (neste caso eu estou utilizando números de 1-1000 aleatórios e sem repetição no teste.txt). O código está rodando, porém todas as vezes que eu tento com um arquivo teste.txt que contém valores desordenados abaixo de 1000 caracteres, o tempo de execução fica zerado. 
Quando uma colega conversou com o professor que estava testando com 10.000 caracteres, ele sorriu e falou para testando de 10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200... e por ai vai. Existe alguma forma de fazer a contagem do tempo que o algoritmo leva para executar para que funcione tanto em entradas baixas quanto em entradas maiores?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define TAM 1000

void SelectionSort_1();


int main (){        

    int iCont, jCont, aux = 0, vetor[TAM];

    FILE *ent;

    ent = fopen("teste.txt", "r");

    if(ent == NULL){
        printf("Erro! Nao consegui abrir o arquivo...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(iCont = 0; iCont < TAM; iCont++){
        //printf("Lendo posicao %d\n", iCont);
        if(fscanf(ent, "%d", &vetor[iCont]) == EOF){
                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
            printf("Opa, tentei ler alem do final do arquivo...\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    SelectionSort_1(vetor);


    fclose( ent );

    printf("\n\nOrdenado: \n\n");
    for(iCont = 0; iCont < TAM; iCont++){
        printf("%d ", vetor[iCont]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n\n");

    return 0;
}

void SelectionSort_1(int vetor[]){ 
    int iCont, jCont, min, aux = 0;

struct timeval  tv1, tv2;
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);

    for(iCont = 0; iCont < TAM - 1; iCont++){
        min = iCont;
        for(jCont = iCont + 1; jCont < TAM; jCont++){
            if(vetor[jCont] < vetor[min]) 
                min = jCont;
        }
    if(vetor[iCont] != vetor[min]){
        aux = vetor[iCont];
        vetor[iCont] = vetor[min];
        vetor[min] = aux;
     }
  }

gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
printf ("Total time = %.8f seconds\n",
         (double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 +
         (double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec));
}
```

Comment: Você fala de tempo assintótico? Que permite saber que o tempo de execução do `selection sort` vai crescer de acordo com o quadrado da entrada? Que o do `insertion sort` é quadrático no caso médio mas linear no melhor caso? Que o `merge sort` sempre executará `n log n` passos?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não compreendi 100% o que falastes, pois em uma outra matéria, estou aprendendo agora sobre análise assintótica, mas o que preciso é saber quanto tempo o bubble/selection/merge.. demorou para ordenar o arquivo embaralhado. Obrigado.

Comment: Então é só chamar a função que pega (em milis) a hora do sistema ou o tempo em que o programa está no ar. Uma antes de ordenar, outra depois, e faz a diferença. Eu não lembro qual o nome da função, mas acho que é a `time` da `time.h`

Comment: Vou dar uma boa pesquisada então sobre a biblioteca time. O ruim é que em português é um pouco difícil de encontrar, mas já que não tem jeito e preciso trabalhar o inglês, vamos pra gringa.. kkk Obrigado pela dica, caso consiga posto aqui o resultado!!

Comment: só não se esqueça de que será uma resposta :-) Não respondemos nossas dúvidas nas perguntas. Tem gente que esquece disso, então preferi logo deixar o alerta

Comment: Exemplos de auto-respondidas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311780/64969 ; https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/314163/64969

Comment: Obrigado!! kkk vou usar o botão resposta logo abaixo. :D

Answer (score 1):

Tem a função clock() da biblioteca timer.h, com ela você obtêm a quantidade de clocks do processador :)

Pra usar é fácil, primeiro você captura o clock antes de começar a ordenação e depois logo quando acaba a ordenação, e pra obter o tempo entre eles você subtrai os clocks e dividi pela constante CLOCKS_PER_SEC, muito semelhante a esse código.

```
/* clock example: frequency of primes */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* clock_t, clock, CLOCKS_PER_SEC */
#include <math.h>       /* sqrt */

int frequency_of_primes (int n) {
  int i,j;
  int freq=n-1;
  for (i=2; i<=n; ++i) for (j=sqrt(i);j>1;--j) if (i%j==0) {--freq; break;}
  return freq;
}

int main ()
{
  clock_t t;
  int f;
  t = clock();
  printf ("Calculating...\n");
  f = frequency_of_primes (99999);
  printf ("The number of primes lower than 100,000 is: %d\n",f);
  t = clock() - t;
  printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```