# Qual é a diferença entre Request::wantsJson() e Request::ajax()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

No Laravel 4, eu costumava usar o método `Request::ajax()` para saber e a requisição era um XHR.

Quando comecei a usar o Laravel 5, percebi que estava sendo mais usado nos tutorais o `Request::wantsJson()`. Porém, percebi que `Request::ajax()` ainda existe no Laravel 5.

Eu queria saber:

- Qual é a diferença entre os métodos de checagem `wantsJson()` e `ajax()`?

Comment: `ajax` permite outro `content-type` que não JSON?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é exatamente essa resposta que eu quero que seja dada. muita gente que usa Laravel acha que são coisas iguais.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ajax usa qualquer tipo passado no accepts, ou seja pode trabalhar com texto, xml, json e "binários"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, vamos olhar o código-fonte de ambas?

WantsJson:

```
public function wantsJson()
{
    $acceptable = $this->getAcceptableContentTypes();

    return isset($acceptable[0]) && $acceptable[0] == 'application/json';
}
```

Ajax:

```
public function ajax()
{
    return $this->isXmlHttpRequest();
}
```

O método `wantsJson` verifica se o header `accept` possui o valor `application/json`. Isso significa que a aplicação está dizendo, através do header, que aceita uma resposta do tipo `application/json`.

O nome do método em si, traduzido, é algo como: "Quer JSON?".

Já o método `ajax` tem como finalidade verificar se a requisição é um *Xml Http Request*, ou seja, se foi feita através do Ajax.

Note que, uma requisição ajax, pode ser retornado HTML, XML, JSON, entre outras coisas.

No caso específico de quem usa AngularJS no front-end, eu recomendaria muito usar `wantJson()`, pois o angular sempre envia esse header `accept` em cada requisição.